# Code-Splitting in ReactJS Components with Webpack in Ruby On Rails App

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack

I am using ReactJS components inside Rails application using Webpack gem. But React components are loaded only for the relevant places inside Rails application layout. If I have 3 different React components, it gives `Target container is not a DOM element.` error in each pages. 
The reason is I have following render calls in each React files.
`ReactDOM.render(<One />, document.getElementById('firstSection'));`
`ReactDOM.render(<Two />, document.getElementById('secondSection'));`
`ReactDOM.render(<Three />, document.getElementById('thirdSection'));`

Furthermore, I import these components to `javascript/packs/application.js` as bellow.

```
import One from './Components/One'
import Two from './Components/Two'
import Three from './Components/Three'
```

In order to fix my issue, I want to split these files using routes. Does anyone know how to do this? Or any other solution would be appreciated. 
 All the tutorials are only for complete react application and, My case is different.

Comment: what is the return of `document.getElementById('firstSection')`

Comment: This returns a list (<ul><li>...). and the second, Third are also return another lists elements but in different pages.

Comment: you have tested it at the time as `ReactDOM.render` runs? (you checked using breakpoints or printing just before the render call?)

Comment: maybe the element should be an empty div, so react can render your components there?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could fix this issue by studying more about [Webpack](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) and ReactJs. Steps are below. 
1. I used [react-rails](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) Gem.
2. Removed calling `ReactDOM.render();` function in each components. 
Instead, I added `<%= react_component("One", { user_id: 1 }) %>` for relavent places where I want to call React Components in Rails views.
**Tips**:
I had to run these commands to make `app/javascript/packs/application.js` and `app/javascript/packs/server_rendering.js` files.

```
   $ bundle install
   $ rails webpacker:install       # OR (on rails version < 5.0) rake webpacker:install
   $ rails webpacker:install:react # OR (on rails version < 5.0) rake webpacker:install:react
   $ rails generate react:install
```

This works well. For more information read [React-Rails](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) Gem Documentation.